# Blazor server 8 base element not showing styles on App.razor after publish

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have created a Blazor 8 server app, MyBlazor.

When I run `dotnet watch run`, the styles would show normally.

However, after I published the app with `dotnet publish` and deployed on IIS, the styles did not show.

I solved it by changing the base element URL on `App.razor`.

**Orginal URL**

```
<base href="/" >
```

**New URL that works after publish**

```
<base href="/MyBlazor/" />
```

It didn't happen on .NET 6 nor 7.

What is the cause of this issue?

Is this a mistype by me or Microsoft?

Thank you.

Comment: `deployed on IIS` --> did you deploy your blazor app in a sub site? If yes, then it's required to add the app name in the base url. you can see this section for explaining [IIS sub-application hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#iis)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can easily reproduce this issue, when we publish the blazor web app in the main website, everything will work good, but if we publish the blazor web app in the sub application, the issue would occur, because in blazor web app .net 8, we have `<base href="/" />` in `App.razor`, but we but we have `<base href="~/" />` in blazor server in .net 7 `Pages/_Host.cshtml`.

And after publishing .net 8 web app to IIS, no matter we publish it to the main app or the sub app, the request url will always be `localhost:port/xxxx`, it won't add the sub app name when hosting in sub app. Then the issue occurred.

[image]

Checking [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#configure-the-app-base-path) and compare .net 8 document with .net 7, we will find they have different behavior for the base url.

Comment: So my solution was indeed legit. But it would be very annoying to switch the base URL everytime I publish the system. I would use ``app.UsePathBase("/MyBlazor");`` in ``Program.cs`` instead.

Comment: yes, and we can also create configuration file and store the base path inside it.